# Update empty JSON array with new values using Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

**Background**

I'm currently creating a tracking system that is meant to track parts that get sent and received from our technicians.  When we need to send parts to a tech is when we begin our tracking.  The values of the parts that are being sent along with the technician that is receiving them get inserted into a table in my database, and the rest of the values are initialized to empty values.  Once we receive the old parts back from the technician, we then update the necessary fields and update the values in our table.

**The Problem**

As I stated before, when I insert a new row into my table I need to initialize empty values for some of my fields which includes the `PartsReceived` column, which is of type JSON.  I initialize this to be an empty array essentially.  The problem I'm facing is coming up with a solution to update this column in my table once the old parts are received.  I know about `JSON_ARRAY_INSERT()` and `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()`, but I'm just not quite sure how to write a procedure that would achieve what I'm looking for.

Here is how I expect my `PartsReceived` column to be formatted after updating it

**Before**
`[]`

**After**
`[{"id":311},{"id":301},{"id":122}]`

The call to my procedure using Nodejs

```
export const updateTracking = (obj) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {        
        try {
            const updateItem = `UPDATE mydb.tracking SET JSON_ARRAY_INSERT()??? WHERE ID = '${obj.ID}'`

            const response = await db(updateTracking, `Updating Tracking`);
            resolve(response);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR tracking.updateTracking: " + e);

            reject(e);
        } 
    });
};
```

My initial thought is to place all the parts into list and then create a for loop which will call the `JSON_ARRAY_INSERT()` or `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()` for each part in the list, but if there is a way to just place all of them in there at once without a loop then that would be my preferred way to go.

I've tried looking online for a solution to this, but I couldn't find any that helped.  If anyone knows how I should write this procedure, then you would be doing me a big favor.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is likely open to SQL injection attacks.  Use a proper parameterized query to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Brad thanks, but that has nothing to do with what I'm asking.

Comment: What, would you rather I have not said anything?  You'll note that I posted this as a comment, not as an answer to your question.